# How to simplify null checks in dart

Tags: dart

What are the possible ways to simplify null checks in dart code given below:

The code given below checks whether passed parameters are null or empty and assigns them to correct values.

```
bool showBasicDialog = false;
String startPath = '';
String frameToolID = '';
String path = '';
String host = '';
String frameToolName = '';

/// for opening a frame tool
void openFrameTool(
  String frameToolNameInp,
  String toolIDInp,
  String pathInp,
  String hostInp,
) async {
  if (frameToolNameInp != null && frameToolNameInp.isNotEmpty) {
    frameToolName = frameToolNameInp;
  }
  if (toolIDInp != null && toolIDInp.isNotEmpty) {
    frameToolID = toolIDInp;
  }
  if (pathInp != null && pathInp.isNotEmpty) {
    path = pathInp;
  }
  if (hostInp != null && hostInp.isNotEmpty) {
    host = hostInp;
  }
  showBasicDialog = true;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
  String _valueOrDefault(String value, String defaultValue) => (value?.isNotEmpty ?? false) ? value : defaultValue;

  ...

  frameToolName = _valueOrDefault(frameToolNameInp, frameToolName);

  frameToolID = _valueOrDefault(toolIDInp, frameToolID);

  path = _valueOrDefault(pathInp, path);
  
  host = _valueOrDefault(hostInp, host);
  
  showBasicDialog = true;
```

Comment: In dart 2.10 `default` is a reserved word so can't be used as a parameter. But even after fixing that, the above function won't compile in dart with numerous errors incl. `A value of type 'bool' can't be returned from function '_valueOrDefault' because it has a return type of 'String'`.

Comment: I mixed up ? and :. Thanks for the hint - fixed.